# Geocoding API form submit

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-geocoder

So I have a form that the user completes and I'm trying to submit the geocoded object with the form so google maps API can plot it.

HTML:

```
<form name="add" onsubmit="submits()" action="index.php" method="post">
    Resource Name: <textarea name="name" type="text"></textarea><br><br>
    Resource Type: <textarea name="type" type="text"  ></textarea><br><br>
    Street Number: <input type="number" id = "streetnum" name="streetnum"><br> 
    Street Name: <input type="text" id="streetnam" name="streetnam"><br> 
    City: <input type="text" id="city" name="city"> 
    State: <input type="text" id="state" name= "state"> <br><br>
    Resource Start Date: <input type="date" name="start" id="start"/> <br>
    Resource End Date: <input type="date" name="end" id="end">
    <input type="text" name="addressobject" id="addressobject" style="display:none" >
    <input type= "checkbox" name="annual" id= "annual" value="annual">Annual<br><br>
    <div id="new">
    </div>
    Details: <textarea name="details" rows=5  type="text" ></textarea>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Create Event"/>

    <button type="button" onclick="addNew()">Add more date fields</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="deleteAtt()">Delete a date field</button>
</form>
```

Javscript:

```
<script>
function submits(){
    var address= document.getElementById("streetnum").value + " " + document.getElementById("streetnam").value+ ", " + document.getElementById("city").value+", " + document.getElementById("state").value;
    var JSONobject;
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    if(geocoder){
        geocoder.geocode({'address':address}, function(results,status){
            if(status==google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
                if(status!=google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS){
                    JSONobject = window.JSON.stringify(results);
                    document.getElementById("addressobject").value = JSONobject;
                }else{
                    alert("No results found");
                }
            }else{
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " +status);
            }
        });
    }   
}
</script>
```

For some reason when I call `submits()` from the console it works but when I actually use the button I get the error:

> GEOCODE was not successful for the following reasons :ERROR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. the result of JSON.stringify(results) will not be portable across versions of the API.  The "internal property" names ("k", "j", "Aa", "ra", etc) of the google.maps objects can and do change with new releases of the API:

   ```
   "[{"address_components":[{"long_name":"532","short_name":"532","types":["street_number"]},{"long_name":"Beacon Street","short_name":"Beacon St","types":["route"]},{"long_name":"Back Bay West","short_name":"Back Bay West","types":["neighborhood","political"]},{"long_name":"Boston","short_name":"Boston","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Suffolk County","short_name":"Suffolk County","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Massachusetts","short_name":"MA","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"United States","short_name":"US","types":["country","political"]},{"long_name":"02215","short_name":"02215","types":["postal_code"]}],"formatted_address":"532 Beacon Street, Boston, MA 02215, USA","geometry":{"location":{"k":42.3505906,"A":-71.0911074},"location_type":"ROOFTOP","viewport":{"Aa":{"k":42.3492416197085,"j":42.3519395802915},"ra":{"j":-71.09245638029154,"k":-71.08975841970846}}},"partial_match":true,"types":["street_address"]}]"
   ```
2. The geocoder is asynchronous, the results of the geocode operation are not returned immediately, you don't want to submit the form until the results are back from the Google server (in the callback routine).  Something like this:

   ```
   function submits(){
     var address= document.getElementById("streetnum").value + " " + document.getElementById("streetnam").value+ ", " + document.getElementById("city").value+", " + document.getElementById("state").value;
     var JSONobject;
     var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
     if(geocoder){
        geocoder.geocode({'address':address}, function(results,status){
          if(status==google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
            if(status!=google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS){
              JSONobject = window.JSON.stringify(results);
              document.getElementById("addressobject").value = JSONobject;
              // submit the form now that all the data is available.
              document.getElementById("add").submit();
            }else{
              alert("No results found");
            }
          }else{
           alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " +status);
          }
        });
     }
     return false;   
   }
   ```

Comment: How should I store the results then?

Comment: Well, for one thing, if you read the [TOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms), you can only cache that data "temporarily".  The other question would be, what do you need this data for? Why do you need everything?  If all you need is the coordinates and/or the viewport/bounds, store those in your own format that can be translated back into the current version of the google.maps object (give the properties useful names like {lat: xxx, lng: xxx}, and get them using the documented methods .lat(), .lng(), etc; then write code to reconstruct the object when you retrieve it from your server)

Comment: Your question states `So I have a form that the user completes and I'm trying to submit the geocoded object with the form so google maps API can plot it.`  Why do you need to store the geocoder response in the database to display it on the map?  You can display it on the map when it comes back from the server without passing it through your database.  In all likelihood, all you really need are the coordinates of the "best" result stored in your database.

Comment: I just thought that geocoding the address every time to display it on the map takes time so I wanted to store it. Would it be reasonable to store results[0].geometry.location? Because geocode is async, I would have to use AJAX to submit the form results right?